# OnTouchListener не работает

Tags: android, камера, ontouchlistener

Не работает данный кусок кода, не могу понять почему.
sv- это SurfaceView, которое используется для отображения камеры(это для заметки).

```
sv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onTouch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;}}});
```

Comment: Проверил на кнопке - работает. Так же на данном SurfaceView повешен onSwipeTouchListener - и всё прекрасно работает, а View.OnTouchListener() не хочет. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте другое событие.

```
 sv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(View.getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.v("W", "Clicked");
            });
```

Comment: Это тоже не работает... странно

Comment: Если даже в logcat не пишет clicked, то тогда нужно остальной код смотреть.

Comment: а можно несколько OnTouchListener-ов  вешать на один обьект?

Comment: Можно наверное, но скорее всего будет использован тот что указан в последнем вызове setOnTouchListener.

Comment: Да, действительно, спасибо. Хорошо, а как тогда задать и свайп и тач на один объект?

Comment: [SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) метод onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)

Answer (score 2):

Делал список на основе `ListView`. Нужны были *`свайпы`*, *`скрол`* и `*синглтачи*`. Не хотелось использовать или кастомить никакие `GestureDetector`-ы.

Но одновременное вешание нескольких `*листенеров*` на одну вьюху заканчивалось только тем что приходилось делать костыли которые намного тяжелее чем любой **`GestureDetector`**.

Потому, пришлось повесить на вьюху `OnTouchListener`, из метода `onTouch` передавать событие касания в `GestureDetectorCompat`, и уже в его методе `onScroll` реализовал саму логику `*свайпа*`. `*Синглтачи*` обрабатывал средствами того же `GestureDetectorCompat.